# the order topology and the standard topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given any totally ordered set $X$ with order relation $\le$, declare a set $V \subset X$ o be open if for every $x \in V$ there exists a set $I$ which is an interval $\{y \in X: a< y< b\}$ for some $a,b \in X$, a ray $\{y \in X: a < y\}$ for some $a \in X$, the ray $\{y \in X: y < b\}$ for some $b \in X$, or the whole space $X$, which contains $x$ and is contained in $V$. Let $F$ be the set of all open subsets of $X$. Show that $(X, F)$ is a topology which is Hausdorff. Show that on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ (with the standard ordering $\le$), the order topology matches the standard topology (i.e. the topology arising from the standard metric). If instead one applies this to the extended real line $\mathbb{R}^*$, show that $\mathbb{R}$ is an open set with boundary $\{ -\infty, +\infty\}$. If $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ (and hence in $\mathbb{R}^*$), show that $x_n$ converges to $+\infty$ if and only if $\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n = +\infty$ and $x_n$ converges to $-\infty$ if and only if $\limsup_{n\to \infty}x_n = -\infty$.

I can show that $(X, F)$ is a Hausdorff topology. For the second part, let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have a ball $B(x, r)$ for some $r>0$. We have another ball $B(x, r') \subset B(x, r)$ for $r' < r$, and $B(x,r')$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus the order topology can be obtained from the standard topology.

For the next part, $\mathbb{R}$ is open since for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $x \in \{y \in \mathbb{R}: -\infty < y \}$ and $\{y \in \mathbb{R}: -\infty < y \} \subset \mathbb{R}$.

I am not sure about how to do for the last part. I know the definition of convergence in topology (if for every neighbourhood of $+\infty$ $V_{+\infty}$, there exists $N$ such that for every $n \ge N$, $x_n \in V_{+\infty}$, then $x_n$ converges to $+\infty$), and I know that when $X$ is an empty set, $\inf X = +\infty$, though I don't think it helps.

I appreciate if you tell me whether my answer is correct, and how to do the last part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The basic neighbourhoods of $+\infty$ in the order topology on $\Bbb R^\ast$ are $$\{(x, +\infty]: x \in \Bbb R\}$$

(there are only these rays $\{y: y > x\}$ that contain $+\infty$).

Similarly for $-\infty$ and its local base

$$\{[-\infty, x): x \in \Bbb R\}$$

And from the fact these are local bases, and the fact that $\Bbb Z$ is cofinal both ways in $\Bbb R$, the criterion of convergence follows.